# Easiest self-contained proof of the Jewett–Krieger theorem?

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Does anyone have a go-to reference for a proof of the Jewett–Krieger theorem in dynamical systems/ergodic theory? It's quite technical and I'd like to have something to show students. The best I currently know of is in Denker–Grillenberger–Sigmund, but the 1970s typesetting alone makes it difficult reading. I'd love a friendly contemporary treatment.

Answer (score 2):

The Jewett-Krieger theorem is done in the book of Petersen, *Ergodic theory*, section 4.4. It relies on Hindman's theorem, the proof is pretty long though (20 pages long). It is elementary in the sense that it does not make use of entropy theory and the typesetting is modern.

Answer (score 1):

There is a detailed sketch in Benjamin Weiss' book "Single orbit dynamics" Chapter 3, which may be a helpful companion to a full proof.